# Calling an anonymous/lambda function as a result to the get() method of a property

Tags: lambda, kotlin

Assuming we have a class "Test" that has a property "testProperty" that implements a get() method, we can easily assign the get() method the result of a helper method:

```
class Test {
    val testProperty: Int
        get() = testFun()

    private fun testFun() : Int {
        // Some fun with numbers
        return result
    }
}
```

Since this is a method that is only created for the way of returning the result in the get() method, is there a way to make it anonymous somewhat as follows?

```
get() = {() -> 
        // Some fun with numbers
        result
    }()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `get()` is a function with the implied return type, so you can just inline the rest of the code as needed. For example:

```
class Test {
  val testProperty: Int
    get() {
      // some fun with numbers
      return result
    }
}
```